# plsql updatexml- can't update value based on attribute

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working with a database Oracle 11g, and it has some xml fields like:

```
<bookstore id="other">
    <fractionOfbooks>1.0</fractionOfbooks>
</bookstore>
<bookstore id="main">
    <fractionOfbooks>0.0</fractionOfbooks>
</bookstore>
<bookstore id="small">
    <fractionOfbooks>0.0</fractionOfbooks>
</bookstore>
```

So I need to change the fraction from id="other" to 0.0, and id="main" to 1.0.

I'm doing two queries, so first I do:

```
update
  db.mytable
set
  xml = updatexml(
                xml,
                '/*:bookstore/[@name="other"]/*:fractionOfbooks',
                0.0
  )
```

oddly, if I select the record, the resulting xml has missing the last tag, so it becomes:

```
<bookstore id="other">0</bookstore>
<bookstore id="main">
    <fractionOfbooks>0.0</fractionOfbooks>
</bookstore>
<bookstore id="small">
    <fractionOfbooks>0.0</fractionOfbooks>
</bookstore>
```

I don't think it's a nice solution to set the value including the tag, so can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss the text() function after the last node: I was updating the node itself instead of its contents. See:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm